# How can I toggle or shrink the WhatsApp web sidebar?

Tags: whatsapp

I want to view WhatsApp web in a narrow window next to my other windows. Therefore I want to shrink or toggle the contacts sidebar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download Stylus (for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/))
2. Click Stylus icon from the toolbar, click "Manage"
3. Click "Write new style", click "Import"
4. Copy the text below to text box:

   ```
   @-moz-document domain("web.whatsapp.com") {
     .k1feT {
       flex-basis: 80px !important;    
     }
   }
   ```
5. Click "Overwrite Style"
6. Enter a name for your style (e.g. "Whatsapp")
7. Click "Save", refresh Whatsapp Web page.

[image: collapsed]

Comment: This gave me the right idea. I changed the css a bit:`.k1feT { flex: 0 0 30% !important; }
._1Iexl { flex: 0 0 70% !important; }
._3dqpi { min-width: 0px !important; }`. Now I have a responsive WhatsApp Web that I can view on a small screen.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the css again:

```
._2NwAr {
    flex: 0 80px !important;
}
._1eNef {
    display: none;
}
._2Evw0 {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.VOr2j {
    margin-left: -30px !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Or if you want to see your burger menu and the "new chat" button
`._2NwAr {
    flex: 0 80px !important;
};
._3nLE_ {
    left: -30px;
    overflow: unset;
};
html[dir] ._2wfYK {
    padding: 0px;
};
._2Evw0 {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
};
.VOr2j {
    margin-left: -30px !important;
};
`

Comment: the CSS will keep changing, dont believe this will be a definitive answer